# Using Camera after release on Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-camera, android-lifecycle

I am getting this error, after I leave my Camera fragment

> Camera is being used after Camera.release() was called

I have Googled the problem and what I found was that you have to add code to the **Activities** onPause() and onResume() to fix the problem - However, my camera is inside a fragment and using these methods does nothing, I added this to my Camera class:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    surfaceView.getHolder().removeCallback(surfaceView);
    camera.release();
    camera = null;

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    surfaceView = new CustomSurfaceView(getActivity(), camera);
}
```

But i still get the error, any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please add the surrounding class.

Comment: Here is the class http://pastebin.com/PUbYN9As. The only difference is that my surfaceview class name is different to the example post I used... Everything else is the same though

Comment: Please edit your original question. To clarify, I am not asking for all your code, just the class name and enclosing braces.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused which class name do you need. And what specific code snippets do you require

Comment: Remember that in Java all methods belong in a class. The methods you gave above are not in a class. Please fix this.

Comment: I fixed the problem myself abit of a strange way, I have the camera null on destroy method, then in create surface view method I checked if the camera was null first if it was then replace the surface view with a new one and re initialise camera